# How do I get rid of Zenyatta's Orb of Discord?

Tags: overwatch

What hero abilities can get rid of Zenyatta's Orb of Discord?  Supposedly it has a tracking time of 3 seconds where it will disappear if the Zen cannot maintain LOS to the discorded player, but is hiding behind a wall the only way I can remove the Orb of Discord, or are there other abilities that can manually remove it once it's been applied?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

As the other answers have said, killing the Zenyatta removes the orb, as does Recalling with Tracer or going invulnerable as Reaper (Wraith Form) or Mei (Cryo-Freeze).

**Additionally,** Zarya's Projected Barrier and the personal Barrier both remove the Discord Orb, as far as I know. You can call out to an allied Zarya or play her yourself to remove it.

This one is the most situational, but using Self-Destruct on D. Va, getting your mech killed, or calling down a mech, will remove the discord orb from you.

LOS'ing the Zenyatta is the most effective and reliable strategy, however.

Answer (score 10):

According to the [wiki](http://overwatch.gamepedia.com/Orb_Of_Discord),

> The orb of discord returns after 3 seconds if not in vision.

So to get rid of it, you can run out of his line of sight for 3 seconds. Alternatively dying also removes the orb of discord, but is somewhat counter-productive. Also, if you kill the Zenyatta, the orb will go away, though it can be risky since you will take extra damage while fighting him.

**Note:** An orb of discord cannot be placed on someone behind a shield, so if you stay behind one, you won't have to worry about getting one.

Also, as @uni and @yuuki mentioned, some abilities can remove the orb from you.

Comment: There are also some abilities that shed it. Reaper's Wraith Form does, at least

Comment: Is dying only "somewhat counter-productive" because every team has a Mercy?

Comment: @acbabis Heroes never die.

Answer (score 4):

Tracer's Recall ability removes Zenyatta's Orb of Discord and, technically, Mei's Ice Wall can remove it by breaking line-of-sight. Reaper's Wraith Form will also remove Orb of Discord.